# Class std::vector<Object> has no member named 'x'

Tags: c++, vector

I get the error message mentioned in the title when I try to compile something similar to the following.

```
class Object{
 public:
  Object(){
   //Something
  }
  void x(){
   //Something
  }
}

void function(std::vector<Object>* things){
 int someNumber;
 //Some algorithm to get the value of someNumber.
 things->resize(someNumber);
 for(int i=0;i<someNumber;i++){
  things[i].x();
 }
}

int main(){
 vector<Object> things;
 function(&things);
 return 0;
}
```

What could be causing the trouble?

Comment: **−1** because this is **not the real code**. Voted to close as lacking reproducible example. That said, you can'r refer to a member function `x` as `o.x` without an invocation.

Comment: `things` is a pointer. It is a pointer to `std::vector<Object>`. Therefore, `things[i]` is a `std::vector<Object>`. A `std::vector<Object>` does not have a field named `x`. The fact that `Object` has a member function called `x()` is irrelevant. And if you post real code, instead of fantasy code, maybe someone will tell you the right way to do this.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I meant to write `things[i].x()`.

Comment: No, you should not "write" either this, or that. Instead of writing anything, you should post real code, as a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a *pointer* to your vector so when you use `[]` it is treating `things` like an *array* of vectors.

```
void function(std::vector<Object>* things)
{
    things[0]; // element of array of vectors (vector<Object>)
}
```

Try passing your vector by *reference*:

```
void function(std::vector<Object>& things)
{
    things[0]; // element of passed in vector (Object)
}
```

In `C++` when you use `[]` on a *pointer* it assumes you are accessing an *array* whose beginning is indicated by the pointer.

So in your case it is assuming you have an *array* of vectors and `[]` is selecting one of the vectors from that array.

You want to use `[]` to access the vector's elements so you need to pass in your vector *by reference* as indicated or dereference the pointer before using `[]`:

```
vector<Object>* things;

(*things)[0]; // dereference the pointer then access the elements
```

Comment: It was what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
void function(std::vector<Object>* things){
 int someNumber;
 //Some algorithm to get the value of someNumber.
 things->resize(someNumber);
 for(int i=0;i<someNumber;i++){
  things[i].x();
 }
}
```

`things` is a pointer. For pointer `things[i]` is equal to `*(things+i)` so that is not what you tried to do, you need either:

```
  (*things)[i].x();
```

or more verbose:

```
  things->operator[]( i ).x();
```